# Service running without bean class in Tomcat, camel

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-camel

I have limited knowledge of Java and tomcat and I am going through a service code base running on Apache tomcat, The service is using camel as the middleware integration framework. For one of the rest service api, I can see  csfrs setting as below in the config.

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="/v2/abc-service"
       serviceClass="au.com.vivaenergy.esb.service.pumpprice.v2.AbcServiceApi"
 loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
```

However, I couldnt find any class with name AbcServiceApi in the code base which is being meintioned in the above config snippet. Is it something which camel automatically create in memory as the application seems to be running fine and the endpoint is accessible

Is it possible to provide a non existing class/interface in serviceClass attribute for <cxf:rsServer node?

Answer (score 1):

No its not a class from Camel. It may be source code generated from Apache CXF which can do that from a WSDL file as input. The source for this class may not be stored in your source code repository and only the generated .class may end up in your WAR / JARs, and hence why you can't find the source code.

Comment: thanks @claus-ibsen , the service class however in cxfrs is just a dummy class used for route purpose only. If I have 100 resource, is it possible to avoid creating dummy classes for all and use some proxy instead